# How to push an object into a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

First I declare my array as

```
var Ulturls = [];
```

and if try to push an object

```
 var p ={'url' :'https://someurl.com', 'name':'someName', 'id': 'adast'}
 Ulturls.data.push(p)
```

I need to use push since I want my array to looks like this

```
Ulturls = [
    'data': [
               {
                 "name": "Usain Bolt is the real bro_video.mp4",
                 "url": "https://v.redd.it/l1yuug6bcc551/DASH_480",
                 "id": "cln8vskbjlbozk"
               },
               {
                 "name": "Usain Bolt is the real bro_audio.mp3",
                 "url": "https://v.redd.it/l1yuug6bcc551/audio",
                 "id": "cln8vskbjlbozl"
               }
          ]
     'total': 2
 ]
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: You should use an object instead of an array for `Ulturls`, as the keys of arrays are always indexes.

Comment: There is no JSON in your code. A JavaScript object is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid syntax:

```js
Ulturls = [
    'data': [...]
    'total': 2
 ]
```

What I think you're looking for is an object, not an array. Try this:

```js
var Ulturls = {
    data: []
}
Ulturls.data.push({
    "name": "Usain Bolt is the real bro_video.mp4",
    "url": "https://v.redd.it/l1yuug6bcc551/DASH_480",
    "id": "cln8vskbjlbozk"
});
Ulturls.data.push({
    "name": "Usain Bolt is the real bro_audio.mp3",
    "url": "https://v.redd.it/l1yuug6bcc551/audio",
    "id": "cln8vskbjlbozl"
});
Ulturls.total = Ulturls.data.length;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your suggestion